# Merging 2 arrays of objects to create a Map of Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I'm receiving the following data in my JS from a WebService :

```
{
  "fire": {
    "totalOccurence": 2,
    "statsByCustomer": [
      {
        "idCustomer": 1,
        "occurence": 1
      },
      {
        "idCustomer": 2,
        "occurence": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "flood": {
    "totalOccurence": 1,
    "statsByCustomer": [
      {
        "idCustomer": 1,
        "occurence": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What's the fastest way to create the following object as a result :

```
{
  "1": {
    "fire": 1,
    "flood": 1
  },
  "2": {
    "fire": 1,
    "flood": 0
  }
}
```

I'm actually doing multiple forEach to format the data myself, but i think it's pretty ugly and not efficient.. 
PS : the key for the result map is the customer Id

Any idea on how to do this the right way?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: *I'm actually doing multiple forEach* Can you please show us?

Comment: use recursive function to access to any level of data

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the outer object's keys and then the inner arrays. If an result object does not exist, create one with the wanted keys and zero values.

```js
var data = { fire: { totalOccurence: 2, statsByCustomer: [{ idCustomer: 1, occurence: 1 }, { idCustomer: 2, occurence: 1 }] }, flood: { totalOccurence: 1, statsByCustomer: [{ idCustomer: 1, occurence: 1 }] } },
    result = {},
    keys = Object.keys(data);

keys.forEach(function (k) {
    data[k].statsByCustomer.forEach(function (a) {
        if (!result[a.idCustomer]) {
            result[a.idCustomer] = {};
            keys.forEach(function (kk) {
                result[a.idCustomer][kk] = 0;
            });
        }
        result[a.idCustomer][k] += a.occurence;
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Please let OP share effort.